# Google Search - Find number of Search Queries in Website

Tags: c#, web

We have implemented the Google Search in our website. Now i need to get the report like below

How  i can find the details about the number of search queries on my website in a day or week/month?

Thanks,
Velu

Answer (score 0):

There is a web service when I googled your question makes search via "Windows App" not web. Can you implement [this Win App sample](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial74_Google-Search-using-Web-Service.html) on your web app? And good news, there is an article about Google Search using ASP.NET in [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Implementing-Search-in-ASP-NET-with-Google-Custom-Search.aspx).